# Trigger jenkins to build gitlab tag release or when tag is created

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci, jenkins-plugins, gitlab-api

I want to trigger a Jenkins pipeline from git-lab when a **tag is pushed** or **created to the repository** or when a **tag is released** . As of now i'm using **declarative pipeline** and triggers are set using reference from jenkins git-lab plugin :- https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/

eg:

```
triggers {
gitlab(
triggerOnPush: false,
triggerOnMergeRequest: false,        
triggerOpenMergeRequestOnPush: "never",
triggerOnNoteRequest: true,
noteRegex: "jenkinsRetryBuild",
skipWorkInProgressMergeRequest: true,
pendingBuildName: "Jenkins",
cancelPendingBuildsOnUpdate: true,
branchFilterType: 'All'
>         )
>     }

stages {
stage('SCM Checkout') {
steps {
git branch: "$gitlabSourceBranch", 
credentialsId: "$gitlabSshCredId", 
url: "$gitlabSourceRepoSshUrl"
>             }
```

So like this **i want to trigger when a tag is pushed or created to the repository or in tag-release**.

i found a solution which is mentioned below

https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/#plugin-content-build-when-tags-are-pushed

from same plugin documentation but its a different approach how i implement that same here while using DECLARATIVE PIPELINE.

**I want to trigger when a tag is pushed or created to the repository or in tag-release**

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the job when a tag is pushed or created, you need to set `triggerOnPush` to `true` and then [filter the trigger based on the branch name](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/#plugin-content-branch-filtering) using the `RegexBasedFilter` with a `targetBranchRegex` that matches a [tag reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References).

It should look something like the declarative pipeline code below although I haven't tested it.

```
triggers {
    gitlab(
        triggerOnPush: true, 
        triggerOnMergeRequest: false, 
        branchFilterType: 'RegexBasedFilter', 
        targetBranchRegex: '^refs/tags/.*$'
    )
}
```